# Meaning of "curled" in a sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could you please give explanation of word "curled" in the next sentence

> I curled it and it correctly returns status code 400.

And please provide characteristic of it (how much is it slangy?), and another examples of usage in this meaning.

Comment: Yep, given the normal definitions of "curl" the sentence is nonsense.  It is almost certainly a reference to cURL as Benjol states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a victim of 'verbing'. cURL is just the name of a program that the author was using to test something:

> cURL (/kə:(r)l/.[3]) is a computer software project providing a library and command-line tool for transferring data using various protocols.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: in original sentance it was used as "curl'ed", that's another proof of your version